# Function in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I try to use a function in a widget but i recive this error
Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.

I search here and see that someone suggest to use the same metod that I set in my code so what's the problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard(
      {required this.colour, required this.cardChild, required this.onPress});
  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          color: colour,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `final Function onPress;` to `final Function() onPress;`

Comment: This will work, although I would recommend you specify the full signature of the function type by including the return type as well: `final void Function() onPress;`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `onTap: onPress` with `onTap: () => onPress()`

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter we already have the signature of callbacks that have no arguments and return no data - **VoidCallback**.

You can use it:

```dart
final VoidCallback onPress;
```

Also, we have `ValueSetter<T>, ValueGetter<T>`, and others.
[foundation-library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/foundation-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `Function` type is a dynamic-type-value-returning Function with no parameters.

Typically, Flutter expects void callbacks inside its buttons, which means it expects a `void Function` type, with no arguments.

A common, flexible and readable way to work around this is to wrap your function with a void function, like:

`() => myFunction()`

This would work even if your function is very different (e.g. it has some arguments), making your code more flexible.

`() => myFunctionThatAcceptsAnInteger(5)`